# Как исправить ошибку -> (IndexError: image index out of range)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pil

Пожалуйста объясните в чем проблема или это с размером холста или с чем еще...

Полный код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "render_test_2.py", line 21, in <module>
    p.show()
  File "render_test_2.py", line 14, in show
    canvas[self.x, scr_y-self.y] = color or (255,255,255)
IndexError: image index out of range
```

Код проекта:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

scr_x = 200
scr_y = scr_x
img = Image.new("RGB", (scr_x+1, scr_y+1), "black")
canvas = img.load()

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y

    def show(self, color = None):
        canvas[self.x, scr_y-self.y] = color or (255,255,255)

    def copy(self):
        return Point(self.x, self.y)

points = [Point(20, 30), Point(120,60),Point(70,130)]
for p in points:
    p.show()

def triangle(coords):
    a, b, c =sorted(coords, key=lambda p: p.y)
    p1 = a.copy()
    p2 = a.copy()
    delta_p1 = float(b.x - a.x)/(b.y- a.y)
    delta_p2 = float(c.x - a.x)/(c.y- a.y)
    for y in (b.y, c.y):
        while p1.y < y:
            if p1.x > p2.x:
                p3 = p2.copy()
                x = p1.x
            else: 
                p3 = p1.copy()
                x = p2.x
            while p3.x < x:
                p3.show()
                p3.x += 1
            p1.x += 1
            p2.y += 1
            p1.x += delta_p1
            p2.x += delta_p2
        delta_p1 = float(c.x - b.x)/(c.y- b.y)

triangle(points)
img.show()
```

Comment: обрати внимание
`canvas[self.x, scr_y-self.y]`, где `self.x = 20`, `self.y = 30`. итог `canvas[20, 170]`

Comment: также я отмечу что знаю как взять элемент по индексу `item[0]`, знаю как взять срез `item[0:1]`, но я понятия не имею что это такое `item[20, 170]`

Comment: НУ смотри тот лайн что ты отметил он рисует точки на холсте canvas[20, 170] это одна ихз точке на холсте по этих координатах...

Comment: Что должна делать эта странная строчка?

Comment: ну на холсте рисуется 3 точки и потом они должны соденится между собой сделав тем самым треугольник потом заполнить его.... Все

Comment: Ошибка означает что вы пытаетесь поставить точку за границами рисунка. Как исправить - смотреть какие координаты получились и разбираться, почему они оказались за границами рисунка.